# How do I avoid selection box shrinkage when working with transparent layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, marquee-tool

TLDR: When I use the marquee tool to select a box around layer and then move it with the move tool, the selection box shrinks to surround the populated region of the layer. Is there a way to keep the selection box's dimensions, instead of it shrinking on move?

Here's my situation: I have a uniform spritesheet made up of 30+ layers. I need to adjust different sprites in the sheet to different areas, but because the movement isn't uniform I need to do it sprite-by-sprite, layer-by-layer. I would save hours if I could just select a region and move the objects inside the region layer-by-layer, but because moving a selection with transparency shrinks the selection region to the populated areas, I have to reselect every time I switch layers. Any way to avoid the selection box shrinkage?

Comment: Can you add a temporary layer which contains a shape the defines size you need selected?

Comment: extending scott's comment, make a hidden layer with a black rectangle (or other shape) for each region you will need, and ctrl+click the layer the quickly recall that selection region. You can store these masks within groups for the sprite(s) you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but I was interested in this so I tried to think of some creative alternatives. Here's the best one I found:

Selected `Fixed Size` under rectangular marquee and select the size of your region.

Now simply click <kbd>M</kbd> to select `Rectangular Marquee` and then click on the canvas to instant create a selected region and the <kbd>V</kbd> to go back to the move tool (Note: Holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and dragging a selection while on the rectangular marquee tool will also move it as if you were using the move tool). This should speed up your process up quite  bit.

[image]

Another thing you might try is creating guides where the sprites are/will be. Selections have the ability to snap to guides too which may help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are switch to the move tool- look at the top of your screen- do you have "auto-select" checked? if so, check to see if you have "layer" or "group" chosen, and toggle those to see if you get the results you want.

I played around with this a little bit and what is selected seems to vary depending on what options have been chosen.